# what is the difference between const char * and const char ()[]

Tags: c++, string

I found this function in [some library](https://github.com/kkAyataka/plusaes) that I would like to use but I can't figure out out to pass a `std::string` variable to it

```cpp
----------


template<int KeyLen>
std::vector<unsigned char> key_from_string(const char (*key_str)[KeyLen]) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> key(KeyLen - 1);
    memcpy(&key[0], *key_str, KeyLen - 1);
    return key;
}
```

test_encryption.cpp

```cpp
const std::vector<unsigned char> key2 = plusaes::key_from_string(usr_key.c_str());
```

this is how i am trying to call that function

Error

```
test_encryption.cpp: In function 'std::__cxx11::string encrypte_string(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)':
test_encryption.cpp:39:82: error: no matching function for call to 'key_from_string(const char*)'
  const std::vector<unsigned char> key2 = plusaes::key_from_string(usr_key.c_str());      // 16-char = 128-bit
                                                                                  ^
In file included from test_encryption.cpp:1:
pulse.hpp:685:35: note: candidate: 'std::vector<unsigned char> plusaes::key_from_string(const char (*)[17])'
 inline std::vector<unsigned char> key_from_string(const char (*key_str)[17]) {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pulse.hpp:685:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char*' to 'const char (*)[17]'
pulse.hpp:690:35: note: candidate: 'std::vector<unsigned char> plusaes::key_from_string(const char (*)[25])'
 inline std::vector<unsigned char> key_from_string(const char (*key_str)[25]) {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pulse.hpp:690:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char*' to 'const char (*)[25]'
pulse.hpp:695:35: note: candidate: 'std::vector<unsigned char> plusaes::key_from_string(const char (*)[33])'
 inline std::vector<unsigned char> key_from_string(const char (*key_str)[33]) {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pulse.hpp:695:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char*' to 'const char (*)[33]'
```

Comment: Unrelated: `template<int KeyLen>` is not a great choice when it comes to template parameters in this case. `template<std::size_t KeyLen>` would have been better.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well OP can't help that (though I totally agree): https://github.com/kkAyataka/plusaes/blob/master/include/plusaes/plusaes.hpp#L333
In the meantime I'm still puzzled why it isn't : const char (&key_str)[KeyLen]

Comment: @PepijnKramer I agree, OP can't help it. It was just a reflection. Your original comment is still valid. Taking it as a `*` or `&` doesn't matter. `KeyLen` still has to be a compile time constant. ... but yes, you are correct. Now I see what you mean.

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you elaborate why do you think it should be `const char (&key_str)[KeyLen]`

Comment: Ok, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/61rn7Px63) would have been an understandable definition of the function. I don't find the current one that you have found very understandable or useful at all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it is the only single header repo for AES I could find

Comment: @khalid In the library itself, they use it like this: `std::vector<unsigned char> key = plusaes::key_from_string(&"Foo bar");` It's a very odd way of taking a string literal. I don't see any upside to this vs. the way I suggested

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know that is why i am asking is there a way to avoid this without changing the code in the header file I just want to declare `std::string my_key` and use it

Comment: @khalid The only way I see possible is to provide a string literal - or skip using that function at all. Just create it as `std::vector<unsigned char> key2 {usr_key.begin(), usr_key.end()};` if it needs to be in a `vector`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/b8M8cv18q)

Comment: @TedLyngmo tried your function and it works perfectly can you please write a well explained answer so that I can accept it  I have to give you credits

Comment: You can't pass a `std::string` to the function "as is".   The function  accepts a pointer to a raw array of `char`, and the length of that array must be known at compile time.   `std::string` does not know the length of its data at compile time, so cannot provide an array (with length known at compile time) that represents its data.    `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char *` which is a different type from the address of an array (`const char (*) [KeyLen]` where, since `KeyLen` is a template parameter, must have its value deduced at *compile* time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in the library only accepts pointers to string literals. Example:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> key = plusaes::key_from_string(&"Foo");
```

<sup>Here `KeyLen` would be deduced to `4` because the string literal consists of `'F', 'o', 'o', '\0'`</sup>

You supply `usr_key.c_str()` to the function, which returns a `const char*`, and that's not a match to such a function. All template parameters must be known at compile time and `KeyLen` is such a parameter. It must be a compile time constant.

An alternative is to create the `std::vector<unsigned char>` manually:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> key2(usr_key.begin(), usr_key.end());
```

or if you want, create your own helper function:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> my_key_from_string(const std::string& s) {
    return {s.begin(), s.end()};
}
```

and use it like so:

```
auto key2 = my_key_from_string(usr_key);
```